# Simple way to find method 'parents' at runtime?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a simple way to retrieve 'parents' of a method at runtime. (Possibly using reflection) By 'parents' of a method, I mean the Classes that defined said method first in the inheritance tree. This would ideally also work with Generics.

Example:

```
public interface Class1<O> {
    void doSomething(O s);
}

public interface Class2 {
    void doSomething(String s);
}

public class Class3 implements Class1<String>, Class2 {
    public void doSomething(String s) {
        // Something
    }
}
```

Here it should retrieve Class1 and Class2 if I wanted to get the 'parents' of Class3#doSomething. Does any such method exist in Java or is it even possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190642/how-do-i-find-the-java-interface-whose-method-is-implemented-in-a-given-class ?

Comment: This only specifies interfaces though, I'd also want abstract classes, but it could be a good stepping stone for me to find something that works, thanks for the link.

Comment: If `C` implements a method from its grandparent `A`, should it be attributed to `A` or to its parent `B` who doesn't declare or implement the method?

Comment: To whatever classes defined the method first in the inheritance tree.

Comment: Are you interested in overridden methods only or any methods with the same signature (e.g. `static` or `private` methods)?

Comment: Overriden methods, only, but I think I found my solution (It's in the answers list)

Comment: @o__ if one of the answers helped, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190642/how-do-i-find-the-java-interface-whose-method-is-implemented-in-a-given-class)
It was looping on interfaces: `for (Class<?> c : cls.getInterfaces())` ...
You can also loop on classes by using `for (Class<?> c : cls.getClasses())`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly cumbersome implementation, but you should be able to pick up things you need (provided it does what you want) and throw away the rest. Basically, we find the method in the class in question and if not found we return (if you want to search parents even if the class itself doesn't declare then continue search and do not return). Then we recurse the direct superclass tree until we reach `Object`. After that based on what we found, we diverge to seek super interfaces.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class TestParent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // prints Class1 and Class2
        System.out.println(getParents(Class3.class, "doSomething"));

        // prints Class5
        System.out.println(getParents(Class3.class, "run"));
    }

    private static List<Class> getParents(Class<?> type, String methodName) {
        Method method = getMethodByName(type, methodName);
        if (method == null)
            return Collections.emptyList();

        Class nextClass = type.getSuperclass();
        Class parent = null;

        while (!nextClass.equals(Object.class)) {

            if (hasMethod(nextClass, methodName, method)) {
                parent = nextClass;
            }

            nextClass = nextClass.getSuperclass();
        }

        List<Class> parents = new ArrayList<>();

        if (parent != null) {
            // search parent interfaces
            for (Class t : parent.getInterfaces()) {
                if (hasMethod(t, methodName, method)) {
                    parents.add(t);
                }
            }

            if (parents.isEmpty())
                parents.add(parent);

        } else {
            // search our interfaces
            for (Class t : type.getInterfaces()) {
                if (hasMethod(t, methodName, method)) {
                    parents.add(t);
                }
            }
        }

        return parents;
    }

    private static boolean equalMethod(Method m1, Method m2) {
        return m1.getName().equals(m2.getName()) && m1.getReturnType().equals(m2.getReturnType());
        // uncomment if parameter types must be the same
        //&& Arrays.equals(m1.getParameterTypes(), m2.getParameterTypes());
    }

    private static boolean hasMethod(Class<?> type, String methodName, Method method) {
        Method m = getMethodByName(type, methodName);

        return m != null && equalMethod(method, m);
    }

    private static Method getMethodByName(Class<?> type, String methodName) {
        for (Method m : type.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (m.getName().equals(methodName)) {
                return m;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public interface Class1<O> {
        void doSomething(O s);
    }

    public interface Class2 {
        void doSomething(String s);
    }

    public class Class3 extends Class4 implements Class1<String>, Class2 {
        public void doSomething(String s) {
            // Something
        }

        @Override
        void run() {

        }
    }

    public abstract class Class4 extends Class5 {
        abstract void run();
    }

    public abstract class Class5 {
        abstract void run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but it does seem that equal parameter types for some reason do not work with generics, which is a bummer, because I think at runtime the method Class1#doSomething accepts an 'Object' parameter. Do you think this is a java restriction?

Comment: Aha, I just found out that, with generics, there are 2 methods loaded in the class, one with the 'Object' parameter, and one with the 'String' parameter. Very well